# How to create dynamic URL's in Gatsby from term relationships in Drupal JSON:API response?

Tags: javascript, graphql, drupal-8, gatsby

I'm Using Drupal 8 as a headless CMS with Gatsby generating static pages.

In Drupal I have set up some node Types (Article, Image, other...). All entities have `brand` and `category` term relationships.

`category` is a single selection and `brand` is a multiple selection

Gatsby creates pages from my template on URL's like.

```
http://example.com/category-1/brand-1/
http://example.com/category-1/brand-2/
http://example.com/category-2/brand-1/
http://example.com/category-2/brand-2/
```

The articles and image nodes with the terms selected will display on the corresponding url's.

The problem I'm having is since I changed the brand term to a multi selection, some URL's are not being created.

Because of `field_brand[0].name` Gatsby will only create the URL for the first selection of brand on the article node.

```
// gatsby-node.js

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const pageTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/pageTemplate.js`);
  return graphql(`
    {
      taxonomyTermBrand {
        field_colours
        name
      }
      allNodeImage {
        nodes {
          relationships {
            field_image_drop {
              uri {
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      allNodeArticle {
        nodes {
          body {
            processed
          }
          relationships {
            field_brand {
              name
            }
            field_category {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `, { limit: 1 }).then(result => {

    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    result.data.allNodeArticle.nodes.forEach(node => {
      const brand_path = node.relationships.field_brand[0].name;
      const category_path = node.relationships.field_category.name;

      createPage({
        path: `${category_path}/${brand_path}`,
        component: pageTemplate,
        context: {
          brandName: node.relationships.field_brand[0].name,
          categoryName: node.relationships.field_category.name,
        },
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Essentially the value of `taxonomyTermBrand.name` is the same as `node.relationships.field_brand[0].name` when the data is passed to the template, but I can't use `taxonomyTermBrand.name` because the `path` in `createPage` is in the `allNodeArticle.forEach()`

Is there a better aproach or another way to set the paths and display the tagged content on those pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be able to do a forEach over each of the field_brand terms for each of the articles.

Something like:

```
result.data.allNodeArticle.nodes.forEach(node => {
  const brands = node.relationships.field_brand;
  const category = node.relationships.field_category.name;

  brands.forEach(brand => {
    createPage({
      path: `${category}/${brand.name}`,
      component: pageTemplate,
      context: {
        brandName: brand,
        categoryName: category,
      },
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: Got this working! Thanks. Only thing about using the 'name' of the taxonomy term is it's not URL formatted or consistent with the lower case letters so my current approach is not very solid (as I had to format those strings for URL and passing through context). I will have to find a way to relate the terms with their id's in the API as a next step, but glad to have got it working now.

Comment: You could try something like the path auto module. That would allow you to setup custom path configuration in Drupal and then when you pull the content into Gatsby you can just use what Drupal tells you to use. That will help you keep it consistent.